# Monte Carlo simulation - implementing the uct select function

Tags: algorithm, montecarlo, alpha-beta-pruning, minmax, monte-carlo-tree-search

I'm trying to implement Monte Carlo simulation for card game with following rules:

- 2 players. every player gets **same** set of 5 different cards. every card can be marked at the back side with circle, star or square. each card has 3 numbers blue, red, green (eg. one card can be blue=10, red=11, green=23).
- player that starts (after coin-flip) plays one card and says color. if he played blue, opponent has to respond with green. If he played red opponent responds with red. And if he played green, opponent responds with blue.
- opponent can see only that it is one of circle, star or square cards that was played and which color was played, but not the number.
- round ends by comparing the values assigned to colors for those specific cards. One with larger value wins. If same value - draw. **Whoever wins, plays the next round. If draw, same player that played before plays again.**
- game ends after one of the players has score that is not reachable by the other or no more cards.

I implemented the algorithm, but it strangely selects some moves that do not seem to be the best. I have a feeling that I need to adjust UCT selection function. Somehow to add lower priority to the moves where other player takes over the move.

Any ideas if there is some better algorithm to use here. Maybe min-max with some optimizations would be better?

Comment: Hi! Intriguing game, but your description is lacking some details. Does the opponent respond by playing a card and saying a colour, or just by saying a colour? Where do the players choose the cards from? Do they have a number of cards in hand? Do they draw a new card after playing a card? What cards are in the deck? Etc.

Comment: Also, Monte-Carlo tree search is basically a much-complicated variant of minmax tree search. So it's a bit hard to understand your interrogation "I've already implemented monte-carlo tree search and I am now wondering whether I should implement a simple minmax tree search".

Comment: By playing a card and saying a color. We can see if the card that was played is circle, star or square. They choose the card from their hand. Both players get at start same set of 5 different cards. So player 1 has the same cards as player 2. There is no deck, so no new cards.

Comment: Oh! So the game lasts at most 5 rounds and there are less than 15 distinct possible moves at any time for a player. Yeah, the search tree is going to be relatively small. You can do a full minmax-tree of the full game, no need for heuristics and monte-carlo tree search.

Comment: The thing is that monte-carlo selects the tree with most wins, but that is only one of possible paths. whenver second player has a chance to play card first - he can lead the game because whenever he plays blue color, first player has to respond with green - so even if he has red and blue color MAX value, he can still loose.

Comment: Game can actually have N cards. 5 is just an example. But lets say 20 cards both. Then min-max is probably too much.

Comment: I suggest first writing a full minmax tree search for a 5-card game. Or even just 3 cards. And then, once this works properly, and only once this works properly, then you can change to an n-card game with larger n, and try to adapt your full minmax tree search into a minmax tree search with heuristics.

Comment: guess in min-max I just have to deal with uncertanity when selecting multiple possible paths (since I do not know which specific card was played, just type of the card - square, circle, star).

Comment: I think the best the 2nd player can do is draw if played optimally, maybe he's even lost unless the cards have a specific constellation. Most algorithms will play random moves or just the first move if a game is lost.

Comment: I think that min-max is probably not applicable here, since all nodes are flagged as loosing nodes. It basically depends on what 2nd player responds how game will end so there is no sure-win strategy.

Comment: Then use minmax with a heuristic that represents how easy it is for the other player to make a mistake.